# C++ inheritance of private functions while using PCL

Tags: c++, function, inheritance, pca, point-cloud-library

I've been trying to use the PCA module from PCL in C++, but it's been a pain. At one point I want to switch the current indices of points that need to be operated on using the setIndices() function, but to actually make the update there is a private inherited function that one HAS to use called initCompute() or else it doesn't change them (or at least that is how I understood it). Never the less, the code as is, doesn't update the indices for some reason. This is the documentation for the class and everything works, but I have no idea how to make a workaround for this function which they intended to be used for these purposes:
http://docs.pointclouds.org/trunk/classpcl_1_1_p_c_a.html

How to deal with this? This is the error while compiling.

```
In function ‘void clustering(pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::ConstPtr, pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZL>::Ptr, pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>::Ptr, pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr, float)’:
/usr/include/pcl-1.7/pcl/common/impl/pca.hpp:64:1: error: ‘bool pcl::PCA<PointT>::initCompute() [with PointT = pcl::PointXYZ]’ is private
 pcl::PCA<PointT>::initCompute ()
```

This is the code:

```
pcl::PCA<pcl::PointXYZ>  cpca = new pcl::PCA<pcl::PointXYZ>;
cpca.setInputCloud(input);
std::cout << "We're now performing the cluster elimination!" << endl;
Eigen::Matrix3f pca_matrix; //serves to hold the eigenvectors, and never got updated...hence the couts for checking.

for (int i = 0; i < nclusters; ++i, n++)
{
    // the next two lines had to be done so, I found that in a forum, the library just behaves a bit strange.
    pcl::PointIndices::Ptr pi_ptr(new pcl::PointIndices);
    pi_ptr->indices = cluster_indices[i].indices;
    cout << "Current size is: " << pi_ptr->indices.size() << endl;//this shows different sizes on every turn
    //now can use pi_ptr
    cpca.setIndices(pi_ptr);
    pca_matrix = cpca.getEigenVectors();
    // but here I get the same vectors every time
    std::cout << "vector " << n << " " << pca_matrix(0,0) << " " << pca_matrix(0,1) << " " << pca_matrix(0,2) << endl;
    std::cout << "vector " << n << " " << pca_matrix(1,0) << " " << pca_matrix(1,1) << " " << pca_matrix(1,2) << endl;
    std::cout << "vector " << n << " " << pca_matrix(2,0) << " " << pca_matrix(2,1) << " " << pca_matrix(2,2) << endl;
```

Comment: Minor update, just checked whether the thing I am giving as input to the function gets updates and it does, so the problem is not there.

Comment: Could you not just call, say, [`getMean()`](http://docs.pointclouds.org/trunk/pca_8h_source.html#l00189) which will call `initCompute()` for you?

Comment: Weirdly enough, no. I use later on getEigenVectors(), which does the same thing you thought of, but the results remain the same. I'll edit the question with the code now.

Comment: That is strange, because [`setIndices()` sets `compute_done_` to `false`](http://docs.pointclouds.org/trunk/pca_8h_source.html#l00144), which in turn should trigger `getMean()` and others to call `initCompute()`. Are you working with a derived class that has overridden some of these methods?

Comment: It says it is inherited as is. I've added the code snippet for inspection.

Comment: Are you sure that your `cluster_indices` are actually different?

Comment: I have 46 clusters, and in every iteration of the loop I get different number of points as a result (checked), so it should be fine.

Comment: I'm out of ideas then, for the moment anyway :( I guess what's left is to build PCL, and your code, in `Debug` or `RelWithDebInfo` mode (your PCL might already be built with debug symbols, so check that first), and step through with a debugger to see what happens…

Comment: Thank you for your help anyway! In the end I got annoyed, and simply checked how big that PCA object is and it turned out to be 144 bytes. So...I just said delete in the end of the loop and allocated a new PCA object in every iteration. Not the most elegant  solution, but it did the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anyway, I got annoyed after a while and did the following.
I created a pca object at the beginning of a for loop using a pointer, and then deleted it at the end of the loop with delete. It is some allocing and deallocing going on there which is most likely not optimal, but it did the trick. The PCA object itself was only 144 bytes large, cause it mostly uses pointers to address necessary elements.